# How to print the SUM() field from t tables in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

hi i'm new in php so i working on a project and i have to get the SUM of total amount form my table i find the total amount but how to echo or print  that amount to my main page.

```
$sum = $this->Payment->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('Payment.amount ' ),
    'fields' => array('sum(Payment.amount ) as total_sum')
));

Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [total_sum] => 490.00
         )
    )
)
```

Comment: echo $sum[0][0]['total_sum'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this:

```
echo $sum[0][0]['total_sum];
```

This will print out `490.00`.